# Accepting User input in python 3.6 running on Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.6, eclipse-oxygen

```
    '''
Created on Apr 14, 2018

@author: kanis
'''
import multiprocessing
from Tools.scripts.finddiv import process

def function_name(x):
    print("We're here")
    try:
        tu = int(input())
        print(tu)
    except EOFError:
        return
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = function_name, args = '1')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1.start()
```

This is the code I'm trying to run, but unfortunately, I'm unable to enter my input in the console window. I've used the `input()` function on the terminal and it works fine but not on the console window.

I've read many other websites and came to the conclusion that there is some problem with my configuration of Eclipse IDE but I don't know what to do to correct it. Please guide me.

Comment: You're running the input in another process that doesn't have a console window.  If you want to interact with the user, you generally only do that with the main process, not in child processes.  If you really want to interact with the user in a child process, you'll need to use `subprocess` to launch another console window.

Comment: @brendan Can you provide some documentation for this 'subprocess' ? Or can you include a code for it?

Comment: It's a module in the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html)